# Merging duplicates in a list? - Question is more complex than it seems

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

So I have a huge list of entries in a DB (**MySql**)

I'm using **Python** and **Django** in the creation of my web application.

This is the base Django model I'm using:

```
class DJ(models.Model):
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    #other fields...
```

**In my DB I have** now **duplicates**

> eg. *Above & Beyond*, *Above and Beyond*, *Above Beyond*, *DJ Above and Beyond*, 
>          *Disk Jokey Above and Beyond*, ...

This is a problem... as it blows a big hole in my DB and therefore my application.

---

I'm sure other people have encountered this problem and thought about it.

My ideas are the following:

- Create a set of rules so a new entry cannot be created?

  > eg. **"DJ Above and Beyond"** cannot be
  >   created because **"Above & Beyond"** is in
  >   the DB
- Relate these aliases to each other somehow?

  > eg. relate **"DJ Above and Beyond"** to **"Above & Beyond"**

---

I have literally no clue how to go on about this, even if someone could point me into a direction that would be very helpful.

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you guys.

Comment: It's absolutelly more complex that it seems, and it seems quite complex althought!
Dealing with natural languages it's quite complicated, I'll keep an eye on this question.

Comment: This isn't "more complex".  This is "poorly constrained".  "Relate these aliases to each other somehow"?  What does this mean?

Answer (score 4):

I guess you could do something based on [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), but there's no real way to do this automatically - without creating a fairly complex rules-based system.

Unless you can define a rules system that can work out for any `x` and `y` whether `x` is a duplicate of `y`, you're going to have to deal with this in a fuzzy, human way.

Stack Overflow has a fairly decent way of dealing with this - warn users if something *may* be a duplicate, based on something like Levenshtein distance (and perhaps some kind of rules engine), and then allow a subset of your users to merge things as duplicates if other users ignore the warnings.

Comment: Thanks for this! Would this work for **"Above and Beyond"** and **"Above & Beyond"** ?

Comment: If you mean what is the Levenshtein distance for "Above and Beyond" and "Above & Beyond", the answer is 3 (2 deletes + 1 edit). Whether or not it "works" rather depends on what you do with that number (do you consider "Above & Beyond" the same as "Above not beyond", which also has a Levenshtein distances of 3?).

Comment: You may also want to consider Levenshtein distance using words rather than characters - then `DJ Above and Beyond` would have distance 1 from `Above and Beyond`. Of course, then `DJ Mike` and `DJ Steve` will have distance 1 also, even though they are clearly not ripping each other off. Because of cases like this, there is no *general* solution that does not require a case-by-case inspection by a human being.

Comment: You are right, but seems like one of my only options.
Would **Above and Behind** be close to **Above and Beyond**?

Comment: "Levenshtein distance using words" I could make it better by using stopwords maybe? Anyways thanks very much for your contribution, I have a lot to discover and experiment now. :)

Answer (score 3):

From the examples you give, it sounds like you have more a natural language problem than an exact matching problem. Given that natural language matching is inexact by nature you're unlikely to come up with a perfect solution.

- String distance doesn't really work, as strings that are algorithmically close may not be semantically close (e.g. "DJ Above & Beyond" should match  "Above and Beyond" but not "DJ Above & Beyond 2" which is closer in Levenshtein distance.
- Some cheap alternatives to natural language parsing are [soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex), which will match by phonetic sounds, and [Stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming), which removes prefixes/suffixes to normalize on word stems. I suppose you could create a linked list of word roots, but this wouldn't be terribly accurate either.
- If this is a User-interacting program, you could echo "near misses" to the user, e.g. "Is one of these what you meant to enter?"
- You could normalize the entries in some way so that different entries map to the same normalized value (e.g. case normalize, "&" -> "And", etc, etc. which some of the above suggestions might be a step towards) to find near misses or map multiple inputs to a single value.

Add the caveat that my experience only applies to English, e.g. an english PorterStemmer won't recognize the one French title you put in there.

Comment: Thanks Steve, there is a lot of useful info in your answer.

How would **stemming** work for **"Above and Beyond"** and **"DJ Above & Beyond"**? At first impression it sounds like a way of normalising "nicknames", I haven't mentally processed it's utility yet. :)

Comment: Stemming is a word-based, not a phrase-based process.The idea is to normalize grammatical forms to their word stem, e.g. Ran, Run, Running -> Run, basically by encoding suffix, prefix removal as well as the many special cases. Would take you forever except that it's been done, code examples are out there. I was thinking you could transform a phrase into a linked list of word stems. I'm sure there are cases where this would break too (e.g. "Dumb and Dumber"->"Dumb and Dumberer"), as what you're trying to do is by nature a fuzzy problem. Maybe in conjunction with other strategies...

Answer (score 2):

I think this is more of a social problem than a programming problem.  Any sort of programatic solution to natural language processing like this is going to be buggy and error prone.  It's very hard to distinguish things that are close, but legitimately different from the sort of undesired duplicates that you're talking about.

As Dominic mentioned, Stack Overflow's tagging system is a pretty good model for this.  It provides cues to the user that encourage them to use existing tags if appropriate (drop down lists as the user types), it allows trusted users to retag individual questions, and it allows moderators to do mass retags.

This is really a process that has to have a person directly involved.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete solutions but one thought I had:

```
class DJ(models.Model):
    #other fields, no alias!

class DJAlias(models.Model):
    dj = models.ForeignKey(DJ)
```

This would allow you to have several Aliases for the same dj.

But still you will need to find a proper way to ensure the aliases are added to the right dj. See [Dominics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110238/merging-duplicates-in-a-list-question-is-more-complex-than-it-seems/2110291#2110291) post.

But if you check an alias against several other aliases pointing to one dj, the algorithms might work better.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to solve this problem for this instance only (replacing the "&" with "&" and "DJ" with "Disk jokey" or ignore "DJ" etc..). If your table only contains DJ's you could set up a bunch of rules like those. 
If your table contains more diverse stuff you will have to go with a more structural approach. Could you give a sample of your dataset?

Comment: Hi Lex, thanks for your answer.
There are only DJs in the list, but the aliases vary a lot
eg. **"DJ Lex"** could be written as **"L.E.X."**
but **also simple names** pop up like **"Sasha"**

Answer (score 1):

First of all of course the programming task (NLP etc. as mentioned) is interesting. But as mentioned it's overkill aiming to perfect that.

But the other view is as mentioned ("social"), who enters the data, who views it, how long and how correct should it be? So it's a naming convention issue and reminds me to the great project musicbrainz.org - should your site "just work" or do you prefer to go along standards, in latter case i would orient myself along the mb project - in case you haven't done that and not heard of it.
ie. see here for *Above & Beyond*: they have on alias defined, they use it to match user searches.
http://musicbrainz.org/show/artist/aliases.html?artistid=58438 
check out also the Artist_Alias page in the wiki.

The data model is worth a look and there are even several API bindings to sync data, also in python.

Comment: Thank you groovehunter! This is a good source of info for putting my problem in context.

Answer (score 1):

How about changing the model so "alias" to be list of keys to other table that looks like this (skipping small words like "the", "and", etc.):
1 => Above;
2 => Beyond;
3 => Disk;
4 => Jokey;

Then when you want to insert new record just check how many of the significant words from the title are already in the table and match currently existing model entities. If more than 50% (for example) maybe you have a coincidence and you can show list of them to the visitor and asking "do you mean some of this one".

Comment: Thanks for your reply llian lliev! You are right I should skip words,
I found out that they call these words "stop words".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) is a perfect match to your needs.

[This article](http://seatgeek.com/blog/dev/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python) explains the reason it was set up, which very closely matches your requirements -- basically, to handle situations in which two different things were named slightly differently:

> One of our most consistently frustrating issues is trying to figure out whether two ticket listings are for the same real-life event (that is, without enlisting the help of our army of interns).
>   …
>   To achieve this, we've built up a library of "fuzzy" string matching routines to help us along.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only after artist names or generally media related names it might be much better to just use the API of last.fm or echonest as they already have a huge rule set and a huge database to settle on.